# Pass an empty URL as parameter in Swift

Tags: swift, url, isnullorempty

I have this array of tuplets containing strings and a url

```
var notifications:[(body: String, header: String, icon: URL)] = []
```

Now, I want to append a tuplet with an empty URL

I tried

```
notifications.append((body: "some text, header: "some more text", icon: nil))
```

but that is not allowed

What is the way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to allow for `icon` to be `nil`, you need to make it optional.

```
var notifications:[(body: String, header: String, icon: URL?)] = []
```

But you really should make a `struct` instead of using a tuple. A struct is more powerful, gives you more options, and just better to work with.

Answer (score 0):

`icon` has to be of type `URL?` (a.k.a. Optional) if you wish to be able to assign `nil` to it.